# How could I fix the vue keyboard event-binding problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

all! I'm new to Vue. Here, I met a question with keyboard-event binding problem. The related codes showed below:

```
          ...other code...
          <template v-for="(item, index) in chartDataList">
            <component
            ref="chartSelfRef"
            :is="item.componentShowName"
            :key="item.id"
            :showData="item"
            v-show="item.show"
            :activeElement="activeElement"

            @keydown.ctrl.67.native="keyboardPaste(item)"
            @keyup.ctrl.86.native="pasteComponent"

            @click.native="closeContextmenu"
            @contextmenu.prevent.native="openContextmenu($event, item)"
            @mousedown.native.stop="configChart(index)"
            @getRefLineParams="getRefLineParams"
            @delSingleText="delSingleText"
            >
            </component>
          </template>
          ...other code...
```

Here I wanna add two keyboard event-listeners on `<component>`; however, they all doesn't work. As the `<component>` is a custom component, so the `native` attribute is required (I've tried to delete the `native` attribute, cannot work either); I also tried to use add global keyboard event-listener in `mounted` or `created` lifecycle, the good thing is the related methods can be triggered, but, by using this approach, I cannot pass the parameter `item` to the function `pasteComponent`, so this approach is also not work for me. So, could anyone provide me any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to reproduce this and took a look at the documentations. Looks like `key modifiers` can only be triggered in inputs, when not combined with `@click`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use it like this on vue element

```
@keyup.native="keyFunction($event,item)"
```

And in function

```
keyFunction(event,item) {
    if(event.keyCode === 67){
        this.keyboardPaste(item);
    }
    else if(event.keyCode === 86){
        this.pasteComponent();
    }
},
```

This is what works for me in vue 2.6 . Sorry if my answer is not detailed.